# (Discord) SQLite 2 values 1 column error

Tags: javascript, database, sqlite, discord, discord.js

I'm a discord bot developer and switched to SQLite I previously had some errors and problems with it but that got fixed. After I created multiple tables I'm getting an error I can't seem to figure out this is the error:

```
(node:17024) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: SQLITE_ERROR: 2 values for 1 columns
(node:17024) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate
the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

I looked at all the tables, columns, values but nothing seems to be wrong this is my code:

```
client.sql.get(`SELECT * FROM settings WHERE guildid = "${message.guild.id}"`).then(row => {
        if(!row) {
            client.sql.run(`INSERT INTO settings (guildid, prefix, lang, color, admin, mod, user, autor, channel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, [message.guild.id, '!', 'en', '#ffffff', 'admin', 'mod', 'false', 'false', 'false'])
            client.gprefix = '!';
        } else {
            client.gprefix = row.prefix;
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        client.sql.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS settings (guildid text NOT NULL, prefix text NOT NULL, lang text NOT NULL, color text NOT NULL, admin text NOT NULL, mod text NOT NULL, user text NOT NULL, autor text NOT NULL, channel text NOT NULL)`)
        client.sql.run(`INSERT INTO settings (guildid, prefix, lang, color, admin, mod, user, autor, channel) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, [message.guild.id, '!', 'en', '#ffffff', 'admin', 'mod', 'false', 'false', 'false'])
            client.gprefix = '!';
    })
    // FARM
    client.sql.get(`SELECT * FROM farm WHERE userid = "${message.author.id}"`).then(row => {
        if(!row) {
            client.sql.run(`INSERT INTO farm (userid, money, xp, level, chickens, farmers, delivery, wizard, omega, robot, goldchick, cegg, ucegg, regg, eegg, legg, megg, elite, daily, collected, car, house, farm) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, [message.author.id, 200, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, '❓', '❓', '❓', '❓', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'false', 0, message.createdTimestamp, 10, 10, 10])
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        client.sql.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS farm (userid text NOT NULL, money integer NOT NULL, xp integer NOT NULL, level integer NOT NULL, chickens integer NOT NULL, farmers integer NOT NULL, delivery integer NOT NULL, wizard text NOT NULL, omega text NOT NULL, robot text NOT NULL, goldchick text NOT NULL, cegg integer NOT NULL, ucegg integer NOT NULL, regg integer NOT NULL, eegg integer NOT NULL, legg integer NOT NULL, megg integer NOT NULL, elite text NOT NULL, daily integer NOT NULL, collected text NOT NULL, car integer NOT NULL, house integer NOT NULL, farm integer NOT NULL)`)
        client.sql.run(`INSERT INTO farm (userid, money, xp, level, chickens, farmers, delivery, wizard, omega, robot, goldchick, cegg, ucegg, regg, eegg, legg, megg, elite, daily, collected, car, house, farm) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`, [message.author.id, 200, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, '❓', '❓', '❓', '❓', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 'false', 0, message.createdTimestamp, 10, 10, 10])
    })
    // USERS
    client.sql.get(`SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = "${message.author.id}"`).then(row => {
        if(!row) {
            client.sql.run(`INSERT INTO users (blacklisted, reason) VALUES (?, ?)`, ['false', 'None'])
            client.blacklisted = 'false'
            client.blackreason = 'None'
        } else {
            client.blacklisted = row.blacklisted
            if(client.blacklisted === 'true') {
            client.blackreason = row.reason;
            return message.channel.send(`You are blacklisted from the bot due to \`${client.blackreason}\`\n\n*Being blacklisted means that you can not use the bot*`).then(m => {
                msg.delete(10000)
            })
            }
        }
    }).catch(() => {
        client.sql.run(`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (blacklisted, reason)`)
        client.sql.run(`INSERT INTO users (blacklisted) VALUES (?, ?)`, ['false', 'None'])
    })
```

**This problem has been solved due to Rewire Thank you!**

Comment: you are inserting 2 values to 1 column `(blacklisted) VALUES (?, ?)` that might be the issue i'm not too sure if you can show the specific line then that would be helpful. EDIT: according to the table creation query it should be `(blacklisted, reason) VALUES (?, ?)`

Comment: Thank you I whas so dumb I didn't see that!

Comment: @ChickenDev can you please write the solution in an answer & accept it so that your question doesn't look unanswered?

Answer (score 1):

I used:

```
(blacklisted) VALUES (?, ?)
```

and not

```
(blacklisted, reason) VALUES (?, ?)
```

That made it 2 values for 1 column and I fixed that with this above here ^